# Ubuntu taking forever to boot off of USB flash drive

Tags: boot, bios

So I just built a PC, and tried to boot Ubuntu off of a USB flash drive. It has been at the purple Ubuntu screen with the loading dots for over 30 minutes, what should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) (also covers purple screens)

Comment: You should be able to hit ESC during the boot to remove the splash screen and see what step of the boot process it's getting hung up on.